Cookie does not get set
I have a Django REST API that sends with session authentication. And the problem is the csrftoken cookie that I get in response does not get set.
Here's a part of my SETTINGS.py file
# CORS and CSRF

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://123.client'
    ]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = [
    'Set-Cookie'
    ]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://123.client'
    ]

CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False

SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

Here are the response headers:
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Date: Tue, 21 May 2024 12:31:31 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept, Cookie, origin
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
access-control-allow-origin: https://123.client
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-expose-headers: Set-Cookie
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=...; expires=Tue, 20 May 2025 12:31:31 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
sessionid=...; expires=Tue, 04 Jun 2024 12:31:31 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
Server: ...

And when I try to read the csrftoken cookie to set the X-CSRFToken header, I can't get it and it's not showing neither in browser nor when I try to access it in https://123.client through document.cookie.
On what side is the problem here? Am I just not reading the cookie correctly or is there something needs to be done server-side?
